# Can't get Google Drive to work through Gnome online accounts

Tags: gnome, nautilus, google-drive

My computer is on 16.04 LTS with all updates installed. I'm trying to use the option in Online Accounts in the Gnome settings to add my Google account and get my Google Drive to appear as a folder in Nautilus. There's instructions for doing this everywhere, for example [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/196635/an-official-google-drive-for-linux-is-here-sort-of-maybe-this-is-all-well-ever-get/). They all have a screenshot similar to that one, where in the Google account in the settings there are toggles for "Files", "Mail", "Calendar", etc. This is not what I see when I follow these instructions, instead I have toggles for specific programs and services, like "Empathy", "Shotwell", "Evolution Data Server". Even with everything enabled, I don't get a Google Drive folder showing up in nautilus. I'm really confused as to why it doesn't look like it does in all the screenshots. I've found countless tutorials that specifically say it's for 16.04, but still show the different interface.

Comment: The instructions you linked specifically say to install Gnome specific software and to use the Gnome's "online accounts" tool in lieu of the default tool in Ubuntu.

Comment: I followed those instructions exactly. Your comment implies, but doesn't actually tell me, that the interface I was seeing was Ubuntu's tool not Gnome's. It would have been more helpful to say that outright, since that was the root of my issue. Understanding your implication was impossible until I realized what the problem actually was. Typing "gnome control center" in the unity search thing then clicking the gear icon labeled "Settings" was opening the Ubuntu settings, not actually gnome control center. I ran it from the command line instead.

Comment: You're right. I and the author(s) of your example assumed users would notice the duplicate icons in Settings.